# PyQGIS: How to get field values from a vector layer based on an array of field names

Tags: python, pyqgis

I have a list with the field names and I am getting the values from the vector layer

```
shp = "D:\file.shp"
from osgeo import osr,ogr, gdal
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource = driver.Open(shp,0)
layer=dataSource.GetLayer()
list=['field1','field2','field3']
```

I am getting the follow error if I am doing it in the list

```
ValList = [feature.GetField(j) for j in list]

raise ValueError("Illegal field requested in GetField()")
ValueError: Illegal field requested in GetField()
```

So what I have to do if I want to get the values in the list?

Comment: Just a sidenote: don't call your variable `list`, that will hide a builtin type.

Answer (score 2):

I think your error is found in the for-loop syntax. Try the following:

```
ValList = []
for j in lstFields:
 ValList.append(layer.GetFeature(1).GetField(j))
```

Note that in your case, if you have already chosen a feature, change the last line to:
`ValList.append(Feature.GetField(j))`

The results in my case are given below.

```
> lstFields = ['data1', 'data3'] # FieldsNames

> ValList
['B', 'AAA'] # These are the values I fed into these fields of the second feature.
```

Comment: Iam getting the same error.

Comment: Have you verified spelling for fields names? try at start only one field name, and see if it works. Later you can expand to include other fields.

Comment: In addition - note that python is case sensitive, e.g. in my example 'Data1' will fail, while 'data1' works fine.

Comment: Yes i am doing that correctly.

Comment: @user99 I guess that if you share a sample of your data, or make a reproducible example of this error, it might help.